# Warn"use of undeclared identifier self" when use c function

Tags: cocoa, cfsocket

this is my code in ViewController.h in CoCoa to implement "CFsocket"

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSTextView  *CommandDisplay;
```

this is ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize CommandDisplay=_CommandDisplay;

void AcceptCallBack(CFSocketRef socket,CFSocketCallBackType type,CFDataRef address,const void *data,void *info)
{
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
// For a kCFSocketConnectCallBack that failed in the background, it is a pointer to an SInt32 error code; for a kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, it is a pointer to a CFSocketNativeHandle; or for a kCFSocketDataCallBack, it is a CFData object containing the incoming data. In all other cases, it is NULL.
CFSocketNativeHandle sock = *(CFSocketNativeHandle *) data;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, sock, &readStream, &writeStream);


if (!readStream || !writeStream)
{
    close(sock);
    NSLog(@"CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket()Fail");
    return;
}

CFStreamClientContext streamCtxt = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable, ReadStreamClientCallBack, &streamCtxt);
CFWriteStreamSetClient(writeStream, kCFStreamEventCanAcceptBytes, WriteStreamClientCallBack, &streamCtxt);

CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(writeStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);
}

// readstream operatoion , use when client transmitted data
 void ReadStreamClientCallBack(CFReadStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType eventType, void* clientCallBackInfo)
{
UInt8 buff[255];
CFReadStreamRef inputStream = stream;
CFReadStreamRead(stream, buff, 255);

_CommandDisplay.string=[self._CommandDisplay.string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SeverCreat failed\n"]];


NSLog(@"receive： %s",buff);
NSLog(@"%@",clientCallBackInfo);
CFReadStreamClose(inputStream);
CFReadStreamUnscheduleFromRunLoop(inputStream,CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
inputStream = NULL;
 }
```

when i use c function , it can't recognize _CommandDisplay which i have synthesize ,but i need to print read data to NSTextView,how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C a synthesized property `foo` is backed by an implicit instance variable `_foo`.

- If you want to access the instance variable directly use `_foo` without `self`.
- If you want to access the property by its synthesized getter and setter use `self.foo` (without the underscore)

Write

```
self.CommandDisplay.string = [self.CommandDisplay.string stringByAppendingString:@"SeverCreat failed\n"];
```

or

```
_CommandDisplay.string = [_CommandDisplay.string stringByAppendingString:@"SeverCreat failed\n"];
```

`NSString stringWithFormat` is not needed, there are no format parameters, and you can also delete the `@synthesize` line, it's not needed either.

A small side-note:

If the C-function was outside the scope of the implementation block, you would have to pass the reference to the NSTextView instance thru the `info` parameter of the function, but in this case it should work